# Difference between 1./n and (double)1/n;

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, c++14

I am begginer with coding and i have a question.What is difference between `double exp = (double)1/n, double result = pow(a,rez)` and that code: (at line 11). In my problem i need to solve geometric mean.

```
int main()
{
  int n, a;
  float sum = 1;
  cin >> n;

  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
    cin >> a;
    sum *= a;
  }
  double result = pow(sum, (1.0 / n));

  //cout << result << endl;
  cout << fixed << setprecision(2) << result;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: why do you think there is a difference (other than your example not compiling due to undefined variables)?

Comment: `(double)1` is an integer casted to double. it converts the int to a double so the division is a floating point division and not an integer division. The code snippet uses a double literal constant `1.0` which makes it a floating point division,too

Answer (score 1):

There's no difference. Both versions ensure the division operation to provide a valid floating point outcome. The language ensures the outcome to be in the highest cardinality involved here. The exact terminology for this is conversion rank, see

https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion

Only for clearness, I think you know that:

std::pow provides several integer and floating point overloads for the exponent, see

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow

In order to ensure the exponent is really provided as a floating point value (and not collapsing to zero integer for most cases), the syntax you use is required.

As a further note, only my personal preference:

As far as possible, I'd always try to avoid the old C cast-syntax, even for simple arithmetic types. I think, this looks more explicit, is less error prone since humans tend to have their issues with brackets and the according order of evaluation in programming languages, and is convenient to the generally recommended C++ cast style:

```
int x = 2;
int y = 3;
auto result = static_cast<double>(x) / y;
```